# It simpler to modify the Linux configuration file (perl)?

Tags: perl, configuration-files

There is a linux configuration file of this type:

```
[header1]
key1=var1

[header2]
key2=var2
```

How do I change a variable from var1 to var1new and immediately write Changes (in the absence of key1 create it)?

Comment: [`Config::INI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI)?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aTiny):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Tiny;

my $file = 'file.conf';

my $config = Config::Tiny->read($file);

$config->{header1}{key1} = 'var1new';

$config->write($file);
```